# org.osgi.service.event.Event ERROR(s) on brand new Eclipse Mars installation at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.** calls

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, linux-mint

### I just downloaded a brand new copy of Eclipse Mars version 4.5.1

> eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015 java.version=1.8.0_74
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os
>   linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

---

Why do I have 4 errors already with an empty workspace?  Is there any way to remove the errors or should I just ignore them and this is normal?  Seems to be a SWT issue and I have no idea how to fix it.  Any help appreciated.

copy of one of the messages:

```
Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/toBeRendered/SET] {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.TrimBarImpl@608fe01f (elementId: org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar, tags: [], contributorURI: null) (widget: Composite {}, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer@75f4d8a8, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (side: Top), Widget=null, AttName=toBeRendered, NewValue=true, EventType=SET, OldValue=false} to handler org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler@5abbb273

-----------------
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_toolbar_set_show_arrow(OS.java:12672)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1123)
    at ....  // truncated because of message size limitations
```

Answer (score 2):

I now no longer have errors.  I did a lot of things and not exactly sure if all of them are needed.
1) upgraded Java to 8. 
2) installed libswt-gtk-3-java and libswt-gtk-3-jni
3) sudo update-alternatives --config java and chose Java 8
4) mkdir -p ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
5) sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3836.so ~/.swt/lib/linux
6) sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-7-jre
7) sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/javac" 1
8) sudo update-alternatives --config javac
9) export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_74

The previous steps alone did not remove all the errors.  my final step was to downgrade to an earlier version of Spring Tool Suite and create a new workspace then re-add all my projects.  I noticed that the old workspace retained a lot of settings that I thought I had removed.  In conclusion I don't think Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite does a great job of letting you know of missing dependencies and seems to hold on to residue from previous plug-ins even if you remove them.